# NPM alias node-postgres to node-postgres-pure

Tags: node.js, npm, node-postgres

I'm building a nodejs application that needs to run on a Windows server. I've managed to get almost everything working, but I've ran into a problem with the postgresql driver. BrianC has a pure javascript implementation of the node-postgres that I would like to use to avoid having to build the postgres driver.

Is there a way for me to alias node-postgres(npm:pg) to node-postgres-pure(npm:pg.js) so that any dependent package that tries to install and resolve pg will install and resolve pg.js instead?

Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same issue on my WIndows-based workstation with using Sequelize with pg. I had node-gyp issues, then msbuild issues, trying to get pg installed. Have you found a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [node-pg-pure-alias](https://github.com/WhoopInc/node-pg-pure-alias).

It's a bit of a hack, but the idea is to get a package that calls itself 'pg' installed into your `node_modules` folder. Then, that 'pg' library can [export the "real" library](https://github.com/WhoopInc/node-pg-pure-alias/blob/master/index.js).

See [#it's not in npm!](https://github.com/WhoopInc/node-pg-pure-alias#its-not-in-npm) if you're concerned about depending on a package that's not in the official npm repository.

**Disclaimer:** I created node-pg-pure-alias. (All ten lines of the `package.json`, that is.)